# Data structure and package for a radial dendrogram in R

Tags: r, dendrogram, radial

I'd like to create a radial dendrogram in R, but being new to the software, I don't know if I chose the correct data structure and package.

I've created a YAML file that looks as follows:
[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR8la.png)

I know the exact hierachy of the languages, but I need R to calculate x and y values. I'd use hclust for that, I think?

I found this instruction here for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/how-to-plot-a-fan-polar-dendrogram-in-r, but it uses the mtcars dataset. I'd just like to know whether it makes sense to set up my data as above or whether I should use a different structure. When I try to import the datasets I get an error message saying I've got more columns than column headers so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: 'When I try to import the datasets I get an error message saying I've got more columns than column headers' - how are you trying to import them?

Comment: I've used the 'Import Dataset' option underneath the 'Environment' header

Comment: It sounds like your immediate issue is not specifically related to dendograms, but more to RStudio's built in data import tool. If so, it would be helpful to see what your actual data looks like? What file type is it? Can you post it?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=189CGMnVyDUA5r2QNHpE4KY1R9Xkqyqh8

Comment: I don't have the latest version of RStudio, but I don't think it can import YAML. Your data is also in the form of inline R code. You can use `yaml.load` from the yaml library to load it into R but yaml doesn't map nicely to R data types

Comment: A typical data structure for this in R would use long format https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/basics/wide-and-long/ and tabular rather than hierarchical structure

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. So something like this might work, right?

Comment: YAML is hierarchical and is tricky to convert into tabular format

Comment: Sorry, sent that comment too early. Basically, my idea was to create something with the following columns: ID, Language, Parent. Each langue gets a unique ID which will be reused in the parent column to identify which parent each child belongs to.

Comment: And probably a fourth column to specify the level

Comment: you can look at the circlize_dendrogram function in the dendextend pacakge, see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#circlize

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I've built it with ggplot, but might be worth checking that one out